# Image Blur/Quality Loss when Masking in iOS

Tags: ios, ipad, cocoa-touch, ios6

I am masking an image (left) with this function

```
- (UIImage*)maskWithMask:(UIImage *)maskImage
{
    CGImageRef maskRef = maskImage.CGImage;

    CGImageRef mask = CGImageMaskCreate(CGImageGetWidth(maskRef),
                                    CGImageGetHeight(maskRef),
                                    CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(maskRef),
                                    CGImageGetBitsPerPixel(maskRef),
                                    CGImageGetBytesPerRow(maskRef),
                                    CGImageGetDataProvider(maskRef), NULL, false);

    CGImageRef masked = CGImageCreateWithMask([self CGImage], mask);
    UIImage *maskedImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:masked];

    CGImageRelease(masked);

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(maskedImage.size,NO,0.0);
    [maskedImage drawAtPoint:CGPointZero];
    UIImage *newImg = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return newImg;
}
```

after the mask the resulting image appears to have lost quality / blurred slightly as shown on the right of the photo. I cannot seam to figure out why. I know it isn't a major loss, but its enough to notice on a retina display, which is what I am developing on. Any thoughts?

[image: comparison of image before and after masking]

Comment: Im facing the same issue. Did you got any solution for this?